# Polynomial Trendline in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder(year=2007)
fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", 
                 trendline="ols", trendline_options=dict(log_x=True),
                 title="Log-transformed fit on linear axes")
fig.show()
```

I know the above code is appropriately used for a logarithmic trendline is there a parameter for "trendline_options" that instead graphs a polynomial curve?

Comment: I find [Add Polynomial Trend Line Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67219607/add-polynomial-trend-line-plotly-python) to be very helpful